# Import in magento with shopware

Tags: import

I have old shop -  based on shopware, I need import in magento 2500 products, I have csv file with products, but import magento - not working, just error (no attributes or not what else to import properties), how I can do this best?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create attribute which you want to add for product and assign in an attribute set. Then create an attribute using that attribute set.

Put all the values in that. After creating product go to

> System->Import/Export->Export

.
`Export csv file`. check all the fields. fill the data in same format. Also one mopre thing when you are using category names then use same name as in admin(case-senstive). For images use backslash in front of image name ex. (/img.png). and then import file. Refresh you indexing and cache. the product will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

set up some products in Magento (similar to the kind of products you want to import), export from the Magentoshop the products -> you should get a csv file. Open it and take a look on the structure -> Create a new csv file with same structure like the exported Magentod - Csv -> insert your products and import into Magento. You can also write a script which does this for you or you can write an import module in Magento which does it for you, depends no your skills in coding. Another way is using a third party tool or extension, in this case try search on goo....

Comment: I also had a thought - but in manually  to edit the file is inconvenient and too long, thanks anyway, I'll find another way